What are some philosophical aspects of San junipero in Black Mirror?
Recently, I have been told by a philosophy student that they had a discussion about San Junipero in class. This seemed very interesting to me so I'd like to know more about the philosophical arguments that can be derived from this episode.

Apparently, there is a book Black Mirror and Philosophy with a chapter on San Junipero, another book Philosophical Reflections on Black Mirror that also touches on it, and even a YouTube video where San Junipero is discussed by an academic philosopher.
